# Does ConstraintSet works with Group or not?

Tags: android, android-constraintlayout

I have layout with nested ConstraintLayout, and other layout with constraints for apply them to first layout. I am trying to use Group constraint for hide/show some Views through applying different ConstraintSet's.

```
<layout>
    <LinearLayout>

    <!-- Some Views here -->

    <android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>

        <!-- Some ImageViews with constraints (for different layouts images) -->

       <android.support.constraint.Group
           android:id="@+id/invisible_cells"
           android:layout_width="0dp"
           android:layout_height="0dp"
           android:visibility="gone"
           app:constraint_referenced_ids="image2,image3,image4"
           app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
           app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

    </android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>

    </LinearLayout>
</layout>
```

And other layout only with other constraints:

```
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>

    <!-- Some ImageViews with constraints (for different layouts images) -->

   <android.support.constraint.Group
       android:id="@+id/invisible_cells"
       android:layout_width="0dp"
       android:layout_height="0dp"
       android:visibility="gone"
       app:constraint_referenced_ids="image4" <<=== other ids!
       app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
       app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

And appply:

```
ConstraintSet set2 = new ConstraintSet();
set2.load(context, R.layout.item_news_photos_constraints_2);
//...
set2.applyTo(binding.constraintLayout);
```

It's changing ImageView's constraints, but visibility not changing..
What I am doing wrong? ConstraintSet take into account Group's or not?

**Update**

I am trying to use visibility directly in views without Group. Its works (visibility changes are right in layout inspector). But I ran into another problem - some Views broken. I think, because View have attribute `app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"` in first xml and have other attributes in another layout, but old attr not needed! I can not clean old attrs and apply new ones?

Comment: I assume `set.load` instead of `set2.load` at the end is a typo?

Comment: yeah, typo. Thx a lot

Answer (score 1):

I don't know so much about Constraint Group field.

But I am watching the layouts and you are using the visibility="gone" in the group object.

For example, if you have attached some views to a group you can change the state of the visibility of the items just changing the visibility of the group

**example_layout**

```
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout ...>
  <TextView
    android:id="@+id/text1" ... />
  <TextView
    android:id="@+id/text2" ... />
  <android.support.constraint.Group
    android:id="@+id/group"
    ...
    app:constraint_referenced_ids="text1,text2" />
</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

Then in the Activity/Fragment you should be able to change the state in Java depending your conditions.

```
Group group = findViewById(R.id.group);
//Change the visibility when you need it.
group.setVisibility(View.GONE or View.VISIBLE);
```

I hope it helps you to understand Group field.

Comment: Yes, it is right. But it is not answer on my question. But anyway thanks.

Answer (score 1):

You can change the `Group's` visibilty using `ConstraintSet`. The problem with your `ConstraintSets` is that you are not really changing the visibility between them. In the first one you set the `visibility` of image2, image3 and image4 to `gone`. In the second one you set visibility of image4 to `gone`. This means the visibilty of all these `Views` will stay the same (`gone`) because nothing really changed.

To show image2 and image3 on applying the second `ConstraintSet` you should do it like this (in the second layout):

```
<android.support.constraint.Group
    android:id="@+id/invisible_cells"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    android:visibility="visible"
    app:constraint_referenced_ids="image2,image3" />
```

As a side note, you don't need to put any constraints for the `android.support.constraint.Group` tag. It's only used to control the visibility of the referenced `Views`.

Comment: Thanks for reply. I am trying to use visibility directly in views without Group. Its working (in layout inspector visibility changes is right). But I ran into another problem - some Views broken. I think, this because in first xml View have attribute `app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"` and in another have other attributes, but this attr not needed! I can not **clear** old attrs and apply new?

Comment: It  makes sets hard to use:( I need declare all attributes just for "reset"